# Reading file with custom delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to parse a file with some custom input with delimiter in between lines. Is there an efficient way to parse file.

Input:

```
    ABCD
    XYZ
    %
    Hello
    World
    %%
    XXX
    YYY
    ZZZ
```

Expected output:
`['ABCDXYZ','HelloWorld','XXXYYYZZZ']`

My code is only getting me list of all words: `['ABC','XYZ','Hello','World','XXX','YYY','ZZZ']`
Code:

```
op = []
with open('random_input','r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.rstrip()=='%':
            continue
        else:
            op.append(line.rstrip())
print(op)
```

Is there a way to get the expected output: `['ABCDXYZ','HelloWorld','XXXYYYZZZ']`

Comment: If `%` is present in a line, should the entire line be discarded? What should happen when there are delimiters in 2 consecutive lines?

Comment: if the file is small, `fh.read().replace('\n', '').split('%')` should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the strings before you store them in the list:

```
op = []
string = '' # to store the string
with open('random_input','r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.rstrip().startswith('%'):
            op.append(string)
            string = ''
            continue
        else:
            string = string + line.rstrip()
            
print(op)
```

Comment: This won't work perfectly since a line can contain more than one "%" signs. You should use startswith("%") after the rstrip()

Comment: Great suggestion, fixed

Comment: Thanks this worked and getting the expected output. 
As I am dealing with a file, how to get the offset of the starting letter of each word on the list. Example:{1:'ABCDXYZ',10:'HelloWorld'}. Hashmap of offset of the first letter of the string and the string itself.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to split the input on one or more `%` characters and then remove white space from each part:

```
import re

text = """ABCD
    XYZ
    %
    Hello
    World
    %%
    XXX
    YYY
    ZZZ"""

parts = [re.sub(r'\s+', '', part) for part in re.split(r'%+', text)]
print(parts)
```

Prints:

```
['ABCDXYZ', 'HelloWorld', 'XXXYYYZZZ']
```

So, first read the entire file into variable `text` and process as above.

If there is an absolute need to ensure that the `%` characters are on a line by themselves, then use:

```
parts = [re.sub(r'\s+', '', part) for part in re.split(r'^\s*%+\s*$', text, flags=re.M)]
```

**Note that the above removes *all* white space, including whatever white space there might be between words on a line, because the way your question was posted it appeared that you had leading white space in the input. If your intention was to just join lines, then use the following:**

```
parts = [part.replace('\n', '') for part in re.split(r'(?:^\s*%+\s*\n)+', text, flags=re.M)]
```

Comment: I tried all the 3 ways mentioned, I am getting empty string is output list which is not desired output.

Comment: So, you need to 1. make it clear whether you wish to remove all white space within a section or just wish to join lines of each section and 2. you need to show what the actual input looks like resulting in an empty string and 3. which of the 3 options I offered above is causing you grief. I would not think with either of the first two options you would get empty strings. You would get empty strings if you had `%%` on successive lines. Is that the case?

Comment: I have updated last option in case you have successive lines with `%` or `%%`, which would have led to empty strings. in the result list.

Answer (score 0):

```
op = []
with open('random_input','r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.rstrip()!='%':
            op.append(line.rstrip())
            
print(op)
```

Try this way

Comment: This won't work perfectly since a line can contain more than one "%" signs. You should use startswith("%") after the rstrip()